# Pass Value from view to viewmodel in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Thought that this might be a simple issue but I can not figure out how to pass a value from view to viewmodel in C# (EntityFramework 6 MVC ASP.NET).

Unfortunately I'm new to C# (even if not to programming, WebApps, JS etc.) - but this Razor-syntax get's me every time. ;)

I have this div and by clicking on it it would be nice to asign the person's id to a variable in my viewmodel. Then I want to use it in the Controller.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="employee_login" id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pid)" onclick="@Model.userid = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pid)">
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) | Kennung: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pid)</p>
</div>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
 ....

    [NonSerialized]
    public int userid;
}
```

Unfortunately it renders to the following HTML:

[image: Render-View from Browser.]

I read that it is good practice to pass a value from view to Controller via the viewmodel and that's exactly what MVVM-Architecture shows and wants to. If it's common practice to do it via http or something else, please let me know.

Forgive me if this is a simple issue, solved in a few minutes.

Thank you and have a nice day,

Nico

Comment: A bit unclear what your trying to do (your `onclick()` attribute makes no sense). Are you wanting to clink on the element and redirect to a page displaying the person with that `ID`?

Comment: Hey. I just want to select the div on which the user clicked and put its value in the viemodel to use it in my Controller. Sorry, if the way I tried it is very false but I come from development with angularjs which binds it very easy (it's easy because it is client-side programming).

Comment: But thank you all for downvoting my question. In my opinion this happens way to often at stackoverflow. Someone tries to explore a new field in programming or whatever and asks questions for idiot-problems which, some expert thinks, is not worthy to ask and downvotes it. Thank you all, this is exactly what happens on the Internet, thank you in confirming my experience!!

Comment: What do you mean _put in in the viemodel_? `onclick()` is javascript (client side code) and your view model is server side code. It not clear what your wanting to do

Comment: I want to do exactly what I wrote. To pass the value from the div (p.e. 1) to the viewmodel. I know that this is a client-side/server-side issue. More abstract I want to use the value from the div (p.e. 1) in my Controller.

Comment: But how are you passing the value to the controller? Does the view have a form? Are you using ajax to submit it? And what is the signature of the controller you want to pass this value to?

Comment: That's my question: How am I able to do this? First I tried to do it via AJAX-Call with JQuery (to /Controller/Function) but then I read that it is commen to do this via the ViewModel. So, what do you say is more useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114181/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nico).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made an answer down this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to add one hidden field on view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userid)
```

and then set model value using javascript function

```
function updateID(val)
{
    document.getElementById('userid').value = val;   
}
```

and call updateID function on div click

i think this will help you......

Comment: I will try this later and report here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a good solution for the issue (thanks to @NikhilVC).

What I wanted was:
In the Default-Login-View from the ASP.NET WebApp (MVC6 EntityFramework CodeFirst), there should be a list of all users and by clicking on one user and entering the Password the user should be logged in. But ASP.NET authenticates their users with the E-Mail-Adress. Therefor a unique userid which is accessible in the view should be passed to the Controller and then searched in the db for the user to get the E-Mail.

The View:

```
<div class="employee_list">
        @foreach (var item in @Model.allUsers) {
            <div class="employee_login" id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pid)" data-id="@item.Pid" data-firstname="@item.FirstName" data-lastname="@item.LastName">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) | Kennung: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pid)</p>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h4>@ViewBag.Beschreibung2</h4>
    <hr />
    <section id="loginForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", role = "form" })) {

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(@Model => @Model.userid, new { @id = "idinput", value = "0" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "", @id = "kennwortlabel" })
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Anmelden</button>
        }
    </section>
</div>
```

You have to create a hidden Input field which gets the userid. By clicking on the user this is done via jQuery:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.employee_login', function () {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#idinput').val($(this).data('id'));
                $('#password').prev('#kennwortlabel').text('Kennwort für ' + $(this).data('firstname') + " " + $(this).data('lastname'));
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is the viewmodel which connects view and Controller:

```
public class LoginViewModel {
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Speichern?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public List<ApplicationUser> allUsers;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your name")]
    public int? userid { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
        model.allUsers = db.Users.ToList();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = db.Users.Where(i => i.Pid == model.userid).Single();
        if (user != null) {
            model.Email = user.Email;
        }
        else
            return View(model);

....
}
```

So the userid is set in the model and by clicking the submit-button, the function above is executed. It gets the user from the db where the `i.Pid == model.userid` and sets the E-Mail-adress in the model which is then used to authenticate the user.

I am new to C# (especially with EntityFramework) but perhaps someone finds this helpful.

Thanks to my supporters,

Nico

Comment: Sorry, but I don't consider that a good solution at all. You could have added the users email to the view model and generated a hidden input for that, just the same as the code in the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q9Rkuf). And using data models (`List<ApplicationUser>`) is bad practice. And under n circumstance should you ever use `new { value = xxx }` when using the `HtmlHelper` methods (and doing so means you not getting an client or server side validation and having to make an unnecessary database call if the user did not click on a name.

Comment: In fact your `var user = db.Users.Where(i => i.Pid == model.userid).Single();` will now throw an exception if the user did not click on a name. And `if (user != null)` is pointless since `.Single()` never returns `null`

Comment: Dumping a list of all users to the client is terrible, btw.  Just let a user enter a username and a password (or email and pass), have them post the form back to the server, then attempt to log them in.  There must be hundreds of samples of this everywhere on the internets.  Try out a few.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I will evaluate the Code and improve it. But for now all I want is that it is running!

Comment: @Will: This is the Default behaviour of a new ASP.NET-WebApp but in my case I want to change it.